# F# NUnit test sets value as null

Tags: f#, nunit

I have 2 files: Asm.fs, AsmTest.fs

### Asm.fs

```
namespace Assembler

[<Measure>] type ln
[<Measure>] type col
[<Measure>] type port

type Addr = int<ln> * int<col> * int<port>

module Asm = 
    let emptyAddr : Addr = (-1<ln>, -1<col>, -1<port>)
```

### AsmTest.fs

```
module Assembler.Tests

[<Test>]
let someTest() = 
    let x = Asm.emptyAddr
```

When I debug someTest() code, I get that *x = null*, what am I doing wrong?

P.S. files in the different projects visual studio projects. *Asm.fs* in the *Assembler* project and *AsmTest.fs* in the *AssemblerTest* project.

I found an interesting behavior. My problem will be resolved, if I add some file (even empty) to the *Assembler* project. Can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you sure you step over the assignment? Try adding a line `()` and set the breakpoint there.

Comment: @RCH, thank you for the answer. I added a line with `()`, but problem isn't solved. I found interesting fact. If i replace `namespace Assembler` to `module Assembler` and add main function with `[EntryPoint]` and body of `someTest()` to Asm.fs, it will be correct expected behaviour. Sorry for my bad English, I hope I clearly explained. Thank you

Comment: I think the output from the debugger is not always reliable. Is this causing any further issues? If no, then I think it is just a debugger glitch that you can safely ignore.

Comment: @TomasPetricek, thank you for the answer. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community. When I run `someTest()` I get the same behaviour. For example, if make some actions with `x` variable in the `someTest()`, I still get the same result (`x = null`). Thank you.

Comment: What are the project types (Console, Library, ...), .Net and F# version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger sometimes has issues showing the correct values. For me however, having exactly the same Asm.fs and *AsmTest.fs* like this:

```
module Assembler.Tests

open NUnit.Framework

[<Test>]
let someTest() = 
    let x = Asm.emptyAddr
    Assert.IsNotNull x
```

the test passes and if I set a breakpoint at the assertion, `x` is correctly shown as `{(-1, -1, -1)}`

As the code that you show does not compile as it is (*Block following this let is unfinished.* in `someTest`), could you try my test above and/or show your complete test method?

Using [your code](https://github.com/destinityx2/Assembler-Test.git) I can reproduce the behaviour. If I set my projects to console applications, my test will fail as well. So, it seems that for console projects, not having any other file or an `[<EntryPoint>]` surprisingly skips the initialization of module values. For me, the compiler at least issues a warning `Main module of program is empty` where I use `x` in the test. The solution to the problem is therefore:

- make sure you treat warnings as errors
- have an `[<EntryPoint>]` for console applications
- use library projects for libraries

Comment: Thank you. It's really works, when two files in one Visual Studio project. But what should I do, when these files in different Visual Studio Projects? (Asm.fs in the `Assembler` project and AsmTest.fs in the `AssemblerTest` project). I think, that different projects -- main reason of this behaviour. Thank you. I should edit my question.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assume you already tried rebuilding the solution (make sure the dll referenced in the test project is actually replaced!)?

Comment: Oh, I rebuild the solution and now it's working. Thank you a lot! But can you explain what was it?

Comment: oh, I found interesting behaviour. When I add some file (even empty) to the `Assembler` project, I get correct behaviour, but when I remove this file(empty) from the `Assembler` project I get `x = null` behaviour. Can you explain it? Thank you

Comment: For me (using library projects, .NET 4.6, F# 4.0, nUnit 2.6.4) having two projects does not alter the behaviour. So, no, unfortunately I can't explain. If you want to upload your solution (or a functional subset that shows the same behaviour) to e.g. GitHub, I'll check. I do have VS Enterprise though, but if that makes the difference...

Comment: thank you. [link](https://github.com/destinityx2/Assembler-Test). It's solution with test, which doesn't pass. But if you add some file in `Assembler` project, test will pass. Thank you a lot.

Comment: oh, it works! Thank you a lot. I should just make `Assembler` project as Class Library.